# bash: cut specific strings before the last delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

Can anyone help me on this, there are many questions found to cut, but i cant find the solution that matches my requirement.

i need to cut & print the rest of string in each line, `cut` should be applied after `,` and before the last delimiter '.' (dot)

for example:

```
PC109001,catagory.data.picture.aaa-111
PC109002,catagory.data.picture.aaa112
PC109003,catagory.picture.aaa_113
PC109004,catagory.data.aaa-114
```

expected output:

```
PC109001,aaa-111
PC109002,aaa112
PC109003,aaa_113
PC109004,aaa-114
```

expecting a output with first field before comma & last field before dot `.` delimiter.

please help.

thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly do add your attempted code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you(not my downvote btw).

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk`; define both comma and period to be field separators, print the first and last field.

```
awk -F"[,.]" '{print $1","$NF}' file
PC109001,aaa-111
PC109002,aaa112
PC109003,aaa_113
PC109004,aaa-114
```

Comment: you could set `OFS=','` also. Your code would be `awk -v FS='[,.]' -v OFS=',' '{print $1,$NF}' file`

Answer (score 2):

A `sed` one-liner:

```
sed 's/,.*\./,/' datafile
```

The portion beginning with the first `,` and ending with the last `.` is replaced with a single `,`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -E 's/(^.*,)(.*\.)(.*$)/\1\3/' file
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -E or -r. split the lines into three section specified with parenthesis. Substitute the line the for the 1st and 3rd sections only